# Why doesn't Blender find my graphics card on MacBook Pro 2017

Tags: gpu, osx

I don't understand why Blender cannot find my graphics cards? Could abyone help?

My config:
[image: my config]

[image: what my system panel says]

Comment: Not compatible as Blender tells you. Let's see, your [gpu supports](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202823) only OpenCL 1.2, [Blender needs GCN 2.0](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/gpu_rendering.html#opencl), ie. OpenCL capability of [2.0 or higher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_AMD_graphics_processing_units#Features_Overview).

Comment: And even with supported gpu I would advise against putting heavy workloads on MacBooks gpus, due to poor thermals and inadequate power delivery circuitry you will cook them and greatly decrease their life span.